# Grabbing first item in a set

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab the first item in a set but none of the examples i have seen on traversing really fit the format I am using. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function popagateDegreeUpwards(obj, sectionNum, compLev, counter)
{
    var ddl = $(obj);
    var oneTierUpPnl = ddl.parent('.Section' + (sectionNum - 1));
    var parDdls = oneTierUpPnl.find('.DDLSelector' + (sectionNum - 1));
    var parDdl = //How do I select the first element in the parDdls Set???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:first` selector.  Here's some documentation: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

You might use it like so:

```
function popagateDegreeUpwards(obj, sectionNum, compLev, counter)
{
    var ddl = $(obj);
    var oneTierUpPnl = ddl.parent('.Section' + (sectionNum - 1));
    var parDdls = oneTierUpPnl.find('.DDLSelector' + (sectionNum - 1));
    var parDdl = $(':first', parDdls);
}
```

You could also use the `.first()` call.  Docmentation here: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Usage example:

```
function popagateDegreeUpwards(obj, sectionNum, compLev, counter)
{
    var ddl = $(obj);
    var oneTierUpPnl = ddl.parent('.Section' + (sectionNum - 1));
    var parDdls = oneTierUpPnl.find('.DDLSelector' + (sectionNum - 1));
    var parDdl = parDdls.first();
}
```

Comment: aaa ty much sir. I knew it was simple and I scoured the api ... but i was looking in the wrong section (Traversals) lol. no wonder the syntax felt off, I was looking for a selector.